# How to open Arabic text file with correct encoding in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, character-encoding

I have a C# file that has some arabic text in it, I got the file from another source, the arabic text is now scrambled. looking like this ("ÇáãæÇÞÚ ÇáÞÇÈáÉ ááÊØæíÑ ÇáÓíÇÍì"), I tried to save the file in another encoding (UTF-8) but still same result, I desperately need to read this arabic text as this is the only back up we have

Thanks

Comment: how did you saved it in another encoding ?

Comment: You have _load_ it with the right encoding first. Can you post a Hex dump of the first piece? And maybe what it should be?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, Hi, How can get a Hex dump of the file, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try right-clicking the file in VS solution explorer, then choose:

> Open With... -> CSharp Editor with Encoding

This should force VS to read the file with a unicode encoding, rather than as single byte text.

Although you are saving in `UTF-8`, the file may be missing the `Byte Order Mark (BOM)` for `UTF-8` at the beginning of the file. A `BOM` for `UTF-8` files is optional.

**Update**

If the file has no `BOM`, try:

> ... CSharp Editor with Encoding -> Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) codepage 65001

**Update**

The file is not unicode encoded, it requires opening with an Arabic codepage. Try opening as follows, or with one of the other Arabic codepages:

> ... CSharp Editor with Encoding -> Arabic (864) - Codepage 864

Comment: Tried it, and chose auto detect for the encoding type, still same result :S

Comment: @Hassan Can you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: I uploaded the file to http://www.4shared.com/file/drWEGKG9/Service.html , sorry I had to delete some unnecessary lines of code and due to company policies

Comment: @Hassan The file was not unicode encoded, please see my update.

Comment: It worked with Arabic(Windows) codepage 1256, with your permission I edited the answer a little bit, Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

use the following code if you want to load or save to file using rtb text without streams:

```
saveFile.ShowDialog();
rtbText.SaveFile(saveFile.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

openFile.ShowDialog();
rtbText.LoadFile(openFile.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```