# Arabic text in vscode integrated terminal

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I have a python code that prints Arabic text on vscode terminal, the output in the terminal appears in "unreadable" format.

code:

```
print('مرحبا')
```

output:

```
┘à╪▒╪¡╪¿╪º
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: There is a lengthy discussion/answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528462/python-3-print-function-with-farsi-arabic-characters

Comment: @ThaerA , I tried it before but it doesn't work. When I use pycharm or other emulators the arabic chars appear in a right way. I only have this issue with vscode.

Comment: Declaring the source file encoding seems to solve the problem to some extent. Still the characters are aligned LTR. Add this at the top of your py file (in two commented lines).. #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

Comment: @ThaerA unfortunately neither this way. even the arabic chars don't appear in the right format.

Comment: Try this: there is a UTF button at the bottom right of VSCode, click that > click save with encoding > pick Arabic (Windows-1256. Now in the terminal type > chcp 1256 ... This should display arabic text but the letters will still be LTR

Comment: @ThaerA I did it: `SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe3' in file c:\Users\ghanem\project1\playground.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Comment: Did you type: chcp 1256 in the terminal and got "Active code page: 1256" before running the script (that was saved in Arabic Windows 1256) ?

Comment: Sorry, add          #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: windows-1256 -*-             at the top of the file too. IN TWO LINES.

Comment: The same result @ThaerA .. thanks for your efforts. it looks that it's something more complicated.

Comment: IT IS. Powershell doesn't support Arabic. That's the problem.

Comment: Is this a problem in the terminal? If so what shell are you using?

Comment: @BrettCannon I tried all of the available ones (windows shell, cmd, git bash).

Comment: What font do you have set for your terminal? Is it one that supports Arabic?

Comment: I didn't change the font. Is there specific font type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import arabic-reshaper library:
Type in your system command line "pip install --upgrade arabic-reshaper".
Then use `import arabic_reshaper` in your IDE.
After that: : "pip install python-bidi".
And use `from bidi.algorithm import get_display` in your IDE.

Comment: I did the same steps, also I restarted the IDE but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just found the similar problem with C# files, so try to do these actions with Python settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828148/how-to-open-arabic-text-file-with-correct-encoding-in-visual-studio

Comment: This is different. The link you mentioned is regarding a question for visual studio (not vscode).

Answer (score -1):

Yum Just need to Change the Encoding. On the the status bar down click on UTF-8 -->  save with encoding --> the choose you encodeing (i think windows 1256)

Comment: if you use an other editor do you get a right encoding?

Comment: No! I just tried with pycharm and I get the same issue. but the nice thing about pycharm is that there is console that supports arabic.